# while inserting values in database table some values are inserted while some are not

Tags: php

This is my php code. when i enter the values only divisionname, divisionchief, month and periods values gets inserted in the database table.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include('includes/connect.php');
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
$divisionname = $_POST['divisionname'];
$divisionchief= $_POST['divisionchief'];
$period = $_POST['period'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$activityname = $_POST['activityname'.$i];
$unit = $_POST['unit'.$i];
$weightage = $_POST['weightage'.$i];
$per100 = $_POST['per100'.$i];
$per75 = $_POST['per75'.$i];
$per50 = $_POST['per50'.$i];
$perless50 = $_POST['perless50'.$i];


$sql="INSERT INTO workplan_detail(division_name, division_chief, Period, Month, activity_name, Unit, Weightage, per_100, per_75, per_50, per_less50) VALUES ('$divisionname', '$divisionchief', '$period', '$month', '$activityname', '$unit', '$weightage', '$per100', '$per75', '$per50', '$perless50')";
    mysql_query($sql);

    header("location:workplan.php");
    }`
    echo"This information has been added to the database."; 
}
?>
```

Comment: nice sql injection vulnerabilities, nice usage of a deprecated api, nice indention, nice backtick!

Comment: most likely `$_POST['activityname1'], $_POST['activityname2'] and $_POST['activityname3']` do not exist. Same thing goes for all those other variables. You would have known if you had error_reporting turned on to show E_NOTICE errors.

Comment: On a sidenote: you have a huge chance of SQL injection. It would be a far better idea to switch to using either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo), since the mysql extension is very susceptable to various attacks and is officially deprecated.

Comment: No worries. This is just for my assignment purpose. P.S. I am a beginner.

Comment: Can u help me out?? its been hours i,ve been stuck here.

Comment: Are your form inputs explicitly named, or are you using a format like `<input name="activityname[]" />` to create an array?

Comment: @ larsAnders Im using <input name="activityname[]" />. The same line in each row of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$activityname = $_POST['activityname'.$i];
```

generates, for instance on the first loop:

```
$activityname = $_POST['activityname1'];
```

*If there is no input from the form with that precise name, the value will be empty.*

If you have an array of inputs coming from a form like:

```
<input name="activityname[]" />
```

Then the array index will start at 0, and your PHP should be:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
{
    $divisionname = $_POST['divisionname'];
    $divisionchief= $_POST['divisionchief'];
    $period = $_POST['period'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $activityname = $_POST['activityname'][$i]; //right here
    $unit = $_POST['unit'][$i];
    //etc, following this pattern...
}
```

Comment: I have a row of binary status in this table. After approval how can i change the status of each row from 0 to 1 at once??

Comment: Sounds like you should post a new question for that one. I did answer this original question though, right? If you could accept my answer, that would be great, and I can help with the next one as well.

Comment: @Bishal_bh The general process on Stack Overflow is that if someone answers your question correctly, you upvote the answer, and click the checkmark icon to mark their answer as "accepted". Here is the [documentation for accepting an answer if you're interested](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Please put this vardump() function below in your webpage, then put the line

> print vardump($_POST);

at the bottom of your code.  I bet you'll find that those variables aren't defined.

> function vardump($var)
>       {
>
> ```
>   $bgtable = '#9999CC';
>   $bghead = '#CCCCFF';
>   $bgvalue = '#E6E6FF';
>   $bginfo = '#F3F3FF';
>   $output = "<font face='Verdana,Arial'><table width='100%' bgcolor='$bgtable' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1
> '>";
>   #<tr><td width='15%'><b>Type</b></td><td><b>Value(s) and information</b></td></tr>
>   if(is_array($var)){
>     #$element = 0;
>     foreach($var as $key=>$current){
>       if(is_array($current)){
>         $output .= "<tr bgcolor='$bghead'><td width='20%'><font size='1'><b> ['$key'] => " . gettype($current
> ) . "</b></font></td><td bgcolor='$bgvalue'><font size='1'>" . vardump($current) . '</font></td></tr>';
>       }
>       else{
>         $output .= "<tr bgcolor='$bghead'><td width='20%'><font size='1'><b> ['$key'] => " . gettype($current
> ) . "</b></font></td><td bgcolor='$bgvalue'><font size='1'>$current </font></td></tr>";
>       }
>       #$element++;
>     }
>   }
>   else{
>     $output .= "<tr bgcolor='$bghead'><td width='20%'><font size='1'><b>" . gettype($var) . "</b></font></td>
> <td><font size='1'>$var </font></td></tr>";
>   }
>   $output .= '</table></font>';
>   return $output;
> }
> ```

Comment: I did not quite get it. Where do i use this function??

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the insert errors:

```
if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    echo mysql_error(); 
}
```

mysql extension is deprecated, consider use of MySQLi instead. Consider the use of escape string function on your variables.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add echo $sql;

like this:

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO workplan_detail(division_name, division_chief, Period, Month, activity_name, Unit, Weightage, per_100, per_75, per_50, per_less50) VALUES ('$divisionname', '$divisionchief', '$period', '$month', '$activityname', '$unit', '$weightage', '$per100', '$per75', '$per50', '$perless50')";

echo $sql;

mysql_query($sql);

header("location:workplan.php");
}`
echo"This information has been added to the database.";
```

This would give you the query and you can try to fix the not working values in sequence .